# didExitRegion doesnt get trigger when the app is terminated CLLocationManagerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, geofence

I have been testing my application for about a week now, Our app takes some regions for example in the current testing we have 6 regions each region has 120m radius. The app is built by following this article https://www.raywenderlich.com/17649843-geofencing-with-core-location-getting-started

**Problem**

- When I leave the building by walking and even after 1 kilometre the app doesn't trigger didExitRegion when it is terminated. In fact when you open the app didExitRegion gets called immediately and I get the exit event.

I'm unable to figure that out why my application is not being wakened by the Location event, even though Apple claims that for every region event the app will be wakened by OS.

I have set permission to always.

Comment: For geo fence capabilities also when the application is terminated and background mode you need to make sure you get the “always on” permissions from the user. 
The thing is that you can ask for it and the user will be prompt with three options - once/while using / no permission. But the OS will decided on when to show the user another prompt that will ask him/her to upgrade the permissions. And only then you will get then - did you make sure you have these permissions?

Comment: Yes my app has always location permission with precise turn on.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured that out the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` was always being called when there is an incoming event in region monitoring. But the locationManager variable which was assigned globally in AppDelegate was nil, So I had to re initialise into

> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Now my app gets event even the app is terminated